# How to enlarge thumbnail on mouseover?

Tags: images, gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am currently using NextGen Gallery and I want to view full images when I hover over the thumbnail, it is much better than waiting the user to click.

Currently I obtain this functionality in Chrome by using the extension [Hover Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nonjdcjchghhkdoolnlbekcfllmednbl) but I want to enable this functionality to all my visitiors.

I suppose that this should be a generic solution, not something special for NextGen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery plugin:
http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/

If you need help in making it interact with NextGEN gallery, let me know. You ultimately need to add the script via wp_enqueue_script and then setting it to fire on the NextGEN Gallery objects.

(If you do this modularly enough, you might even have the makings of a pretty decent quick, little NextGEN plugin... Release it to the community, I'd use it! :D)

Answer (score 0):

Or alternately, use this WP plugin, which seems to do all the work for you... http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-zoomer/

Comment: Image Zoomer doesn't seam to work and also it does only "zoom" instead of loading the full resolution picture.

Comment: Then you want to go for the first answer; it allows you to specify a high resolution version of the image. It *will* require slightly more setting up, though. Let me know if you need any help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.designhaven.co.uk/2013/10/image-preview-full-size-image-tooltip-nextgen-gallery-wordpress/) that I believe does what you're after but without the zoom (so much) which is quick to implement and is of use to anyone that visits this question...

Just so you can see how this would look without having to navigate away from Wordpress SE, here is a screenshot:-

[image: Image Preview on Thumbnail Hover for NextGEN Gallery in WordPress]